# GDS Exception. 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface

Tags: firebird, jaybird

I am trying to connect to a firebird db using the jaybird jdbc driver. Firebird is running under ubuntu. I have created a simple database located under /tmp/hellofb.fdb (yeah not the best place, just for testing). I am running firebird superserver 3.0. The firebird service is up and running `sudo service firbird3.0 status`:

```
firebird3.0.service - Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/firebird3.0.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-10-25 22:40:53 CEST; 25min ago
  Process: 23411 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/fbguard -pidfile /run/firebird3.0/default.pid -daemon -forever (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
 Main PID: 23412 (fbguard)
    Tasks: 4 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/firebird3.0.service
           ├─23412 /usr/sbin/fbguard -pidfile /run/firebird3.0/default.pid -daemon -forever
           └─23413 /usr/sbin/firebird

Okt 25 22:40:53 XPS-L322X systemd[1]: Starting Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer )...
Okt 25 22:40:53 XPS-L322X systemd[1]: Started Firebird Database Server ( SuperServer ).
```

My spring boot application.properties is given by:

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050//tmp/hellofb.fdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
```

However, when I try to connect to the database, I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLException: GDS Exception. 335544421. connection rejected by remote interface
```

I have tried all possible permutations given by the [jaybird FAQ](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#jdbc-urls-java.sql.drivermanager), I am running out of options. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Note**: I tried to connect to the databse using flamerobin and everything works just fine

Comment: What version of Firebird, what version of Jaybird, what are the values of `AuthServer` and `WireCrypt` in firebird.conf?

Comment: Also tell use the value of the setting `IPv6V6Only`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given you haven't provided the information I asked for in the comments, I have to guess you are using Firebird 3 with Jaybird 2.2.x based on the described behavior.

The error *connection rejected by remote interface* can also occur under other conditions than described below.

#### Possible cause: wire protocol encryption required

Firebird 3 introduces a number of new security features that are enabled by default, but are not supported by Jaybird 2.2. To allow Jaybird 2.2 to connect to Firebird 3 you need to relax some of those settings.

To allow Jaybird 2.2.x to connect, you need to change the following settings in `firebird.conf` (and restart Firebird after changing the setting):

Relax the `WireCrypt` setting from its default of `Required` to `Enabled`:

```
WireCrypt = Enabled
```

Enable support for the legacy authentication protocol:

```
AuthServer = Srp, Legacy_Auth
```

You then need to make sure the user you want to use for connecting to Firebird is created with the legacy usermanager by enabling support for the legacy usermanager:

```
UserManager = Srp, Legacy_UserManager
```

Restart Firebird to apply these settings, and then - in Flamerobin - with a SYSDBA account (or user with role RDB$ADMIN), create the required user:

```
CREATE USER youruser PASSWORD 'yourpasw' USING PLUGIN Legacy_UserManager
```

Alternatively you could upgrade to Jaybird 3.0.4 or higher, which supports the `Srp` authentication protocol and wire protocol encryption.

These settings are described in more detail on our wiki in article [Jaybird and Firebird 3](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Jaybird-and-Firebird-3). This information was absent from our FAQ, I have now added it under [connection rejected by remote interface (335544421)](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#connection-rejected-by-remote-interface-335544421).

#### Possible cause: no user name or password

With Jaybird 3 or higher and Firebird 3 or higher, this error can be the result of not providing a username or password. The absence of a user name or password causes Jaybird to not try any authentication plugin. This results in Firebird rejecting the connection attempt as at least one authentication attempt should be done.